# What does `BaseRandomLayer` do?

Tags: keras, tensorflow

At the very bottom of `base_layer.py` (imported as `tf.keras.engine.base_layer.py` in v2.8) there is a class called `BaseRandomLayer`. The description for this class is, "A layer handle the random number creation and savemodel behavior." What does `BaseRandomLayer` do?